# AngularJS: Delay in fetching Data from rest service causing issue in html while using the data

Tags: javascript, mongodb, angularjs

I am developing an angular app using Mongo as DB and Java.

I am trying to fetch the data from the mongo DB when i click the get data button see the code in js bin http://jsbin.com/aRuWInU/2/edit , for my html page see below the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">
<head>
<script src="/angular.js"></script>
<script src="myscript.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Demo</title>

  </head>

<body ng-controller="MyApp">
    <!--It will fetch data from Mongo Using REST service through 
    the angular factory ConsumptionEngineRESTService-->
    <button type="button" ng-click="getAllData()">Get Data</button>
    <h1>My Demo With filter</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="Maindata in myFilteredKey" class="">
        <h2>{{Maindata}}</h2>
        <div ng-repeat="item in data | filter:{'key':Maindata}">
            <p>My key is {{item.key}}</p>
            <p>My val is {{item.value}}</p>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Issue happens when i fetch data from REST service,
            Delay in fetching data cause me the issue, such as $scope.data is not populated but
            that is used in the below for loop to populate the $scope.myFilteredKey array, so my $scope.myFilteredKey array is empty. see the code for myscript.js

```
myscript.js
    var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MyApp', ['$scope', function($scope,ConsumptionEngineRESTService) {
        $scope.getAllData=function(){
            console.log("hi");
            /*STUB Data: when it is used , code is working perfectly*/
              /* $scope.data = [
                {key:"home",value:"hk1"},
                {key:"home",value:"hk2"},
                {key:"home",value:"hk3"},
                {key:"home",value:"hk4"},
                {key:"product",value:"pk1"},
                {key:"product",value:"pk2"},
                {key:"product",value:"pk3"},
                {key:"product",value:"pk4"},
                {key:"service",value:"sk1"},
                {key:"service",value:"sk2"},
                {key:"service",value:"sk3"},
                {key:"service",value:"sk4"}
            ]; */
            /* Data From REST Service: Issue happens when i fetch data from REST service,
            *Delay in fetching data cause me the issue, such as $scope.data is not populated but
            *that is used in the below for loop to populate the $scope.myFilteredKey array*/
            /*ConsumptionEngineRESTService is a angular factory. uses REST service to fetch from Mongo*/
            $scope.data =ConsumptionEngineRESTService.getAll();
            $scope.myFilteredKey=[];
            for(i=0;i<$scope.data.length;i++){
                if($scope.myFilteredKey.indexOf($scope.data[i].key)==-1){
                    $scope.myFilteredKey.push($scope.data[i].key);
                    console.log($scope.data[i].key);
                }
            }
        }
}]);
```

Please help me in solving the issue, that i want to populate the $scope.data when the for loop executes as for loop is using the $scope.data.
Note:With this question I didn't include the REST service angular factory `ConsumptionEngineRESTService`.

```
app.factory("ConsumptionEngineRESTService ", function($resource, $http) {
  var resource = $resource("/rest/:ID ", { ID : "@_ID " },
    {
      'create':  { method: 'POST' },
      'getAll':   { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
      'get':    { method: 'GET', isArray: false },
      'update':  { method: 'PUT' },
      'destroy': { method: 'DELETE' }
    }
  );
  return resource;
});
```

Please help me in this .thanks For any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the `ConsumptionEngineRESTService.getAll();` uses angular resource inside?

If that's the case (and also if it's using angular's `$http` service), you'll have to process your data in a success callback instead. The result of the resource and http methods are mere promises, proxy objects which will contain the data eventually but not right away. Your code should look something like this instead:

```
$scope.data = ConsumptionEngineRESTService.getAll(function() {
    $scope.myFilteredKey=[];
    // note that you can work with $scope.data in here, because it's been 
    // assigned before
    for(i = 0; i < $scope.data.length; i++) {
        if($scope.myFilteredKey.indexOf($scope.data[i].key)==-1){
            $scope.myFilteredKey.push($scope.data[i].key);
            console.log($scope.data[i].key);
        }
    }
});
```

If your `ConsumptionEngineRESTService` doesn't support this callback yet, I suggest you take a closer look at the documentation of [angular-resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource). The 'cards' example code, line 8, employs the very same pattern.

Comment: :I am using the ngResource for rest, i have updated my question with the factory methos. I don't want to modify the factory method.

Comment: well, the way I see it your factory creates a regular resource, so the code I posted should work as-is. Does it?

Comment: I am passing the value of ID in calling the factory method  "$scope.data =ConsumptionEngineRESTService.getAll({ID:ID});". is that case will work?

Comment: huh? why would a `getAll` method need an id?

Comment: i am using this id to retrieve the data of that particular ID. how to run my code after the data is populated. i am searching all the day. No clue. please help me.

Comment: a getAll method with an `id` doesn't make sense, and neither does passing it to that method. Remove the factory because it adds a useless level of abstraction and use the rest service directly. Then take a look at angular-resource's documentation linked above which demonstrates *exactly* this use case

Comment: It might be possible to use the promises' `then` method instead, as described at http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q, i.e. `$scope.data.then(function() { ... })`. That's a bit awkward, however...

Comment: Now i used timeout and implemented it is working. I know this is not a better solution, i have to try that promises